# What are ` in bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, csh

I need help understanding a bash script.  This bash script auto generates cron job lines from text files found in a specific folder structure.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/home/test/logs/buildCron.log"
CTLOGFILE="/home/test/logs/cronOutput.log"
CURCRONTAB="/home/test/logs/cronTab.current"
CTARCHIVE="/home/test/logs/archive"
NEWCRONTAB="/home/test/logs/cronTab.proposed"
MYCRON="*/5 * * * * /home/test/scripts/buildCron.sh >> $LOGFILE 2>&1"

# Dump old and prepare new crontab files
umask 077
echo "`date`: Starting buildCron"                                        | tee -a $LOGFILE
echo "$MYCRON" > $NEWCRONTAB
crontab -l > $CURCRONTAB
echo "`date`: Current (Active) Crontab dumped to: $CURCRONTAB"           | tee -a $LOGFILE

# Append crontab-entries listed in cronjob.txt files to new crontab file
CRONS="`find /home/test/scheduled_scripts -type f -name cronjob.txt`"
for CRON in $CRONS
do
   echo "`date`: Processing CronFile: $CRON"
   DIRPARAMETER="`dirname $CRON`"
   CRONENTRY="`cat $CRON` $DIRPARAMETER >> $CTLOGFILE 2>&1"
   echo "$CRONENTRY" >> $NEWCRONTAB
done                                                                     | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

Q1) 
What is the `>> $LOGFILE 2>&1` in

```
MYCRON="*/5 * * * * /home/test/scripts/buildCron.sh >> $LOGFILE 2>&1"?
```

I think that the first part `>> $LOGFILE` means write the output to the filepath in the variable $LOGFILE.  However does variable declaration generate output?  Because `MYCRON=` is the declaration of a variable right?  And why are there two arrows and not one like in `echo "$MYCRON" > $NEWCRONTAB`

Q2) 
In

```
echo "`date`: Starting buildCron"
```

What are the single inverted commas surrounding the word date?  Why are they surrounding the word date only?  Does it perhaps mean that a command called date will be executed there?

Q3) 
In

```
CRONENTRY="`cat $CRON` $DIRPARAMETER >> $CTLOGFILE 2>&1"
```

What is

```
`cat $CRON`
```

doing?

I understand that cat, concatenates two files into one,  however the code seems to write only one filename after the command cat.  So I do not understand which two files are being concatenated...   Also what is this part doing? `$DIRPARAMETER >> $CTLOGFILE 2>&1` What are the numbers 2 and &1?

Q4) 
What does `umask 077` do?  Does it establish permission for all files that will be generated within this .sh file?  What if I want to generate files with different permission in the same shell script?

Thank you and sorry if the questions are babish.  This is the first bash script I have ever read...

Comment: Maybe spend some time researching some bash programming? Also, you can type the same or equivalent commands into a terminal and just *see* what they do, yes?

Comment: See 3.4.5 here http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: You need to read about [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Comment: `\`x\`` is an obsolete, cumbersome and error-prone way to say `$(x)`.

Comment: @n.m.: Neither obsolete nor (depending on your keyboard layout) especially cumbersome. But yes, error-prone, and not all that easily readable. `$()` is definitely recommended.

Comment: @DevSolar POSIX/SUSv4 states that *"[...] the backquoted syntax has historical restrictions on the contents of the embedded command. While the newer "`$()`" form can process any kind of valid embedded script, the backquoted form cannot handle some valid scripts that include backquotes"*. `$()` is specified by POSIX, so I'd consider backticks *de facto* obsolete unless you have to deal with vintage shells (`bash` definitely not being one of them).

Comment: @DaveNewton you are right on some matters but not on all.  For instance the cat command question (Q3) was tricky because cat is a command for concatenation but in this case it is being used to output the contents of the file as thankfully explained by someone else.  I knew that cat was for concatentation because I did some research but still couldn't conclude with an answer.  I am sorry I frustrated your experienced-super-developer-having-permission-to-patronize-everyone feelings.

Comment: @DevSolar Well, I do have strong opinions sometimes.

Comment: @prince I'd recommend pumping the brakes a little. Ever consider looking at the man page for cat? It has an explicit example. Instead of assuming I'm being a douche then being one yourself, how about just reading some basic Unix docs and trying some stuff out? It's the most efficient and effective way to learn. It's too bad you're so comfortable assuming the worst. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A1: Assuming that `$LOGFILE` holds a filename, `>> $LOGFILE 2>&` is *appending* the standard output of the command to that file, plus redirecting the standard *error* to the standard output (i.e. writing that to the logfile as well).

A2: The backticks (which could also be written as `$()`) are executing the given command, and replace the backtick-phrase with the output of the command (in your case, placing the current date into the `echo` line).

A3: I'll pass on that one, I'd have to test around a bit and I don't write answers that take more than a minute to type. ;-)

A4: This makes all files generated to have all "group" and "other" permissions removed, i.e. leaving only the permissions for the use intact. That's the default for files generated by the script; you can always set permissions explicitly via `chmod`.

A bit too much for a single question. You might fare better by asking questions in isolation.

Comment: Thanks!  The Q3 is the one bothering me most because the other questions I almost answered myself but I still needed someone to reassure me!

Comment: @prince: Dave Newton's comments are rather spot-on in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

1. `>>` appends to a file (as opposed to > which overwrites to the file)
   2>&1 means it writes all output including stdout and stderr. If that doesn't mean anything, just understand it means write ALL output
2. the back ticks mean run the command and give me the output, in this case the date
3. backticks cat cron is saying run the output of the file. Think of it a bit like calling eval on the file contents
4. permissions settings for the user

Comment: Actually `2>&1` means "write output channel 2 -- which is by default stderr -- to where output channel 1 gets written *at this moment*". The fine print becomes important when you write `2>&1 >> $LOGFILE` and wonder why your error messages don't show up in the logfile. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar So in `>> $LOGFILE 2>&1` how does re-ordering the commands ruin the logs?

Comment: @prince: As I said, `2>&1` attaches stderr (file descriptor 2) to whatever stdout (file descriptor 1) points at *at the moment* (like, the terminal). If you later (even if on the same line) redirect file descriptor 1 to a file -- i.e. `> logfile.txt` -- then file descriptor 2 (stderr) will *still* point to the terminal. That's why the sequence of redirections matters.